# Windows Azure Cache Service using old configuration

Tags: azure, azure-caching

The weirdest thing. I am switching over to SDK v1.7 and a new ACS and I get this weird error after I successfully login. It appears to be related to the SessionState provider for the Azure Cache Service.

I am NOT using the Preview but I am using SDK 1.7 and I am using a Windows Azure account that has the Preview Features enabled.

It's like something deep within the recesses of the ACS/Cache Service SDK is messed up.

Here is my cache config:

```xml
  <dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default">
      <tracing sinkType="DiagnosticSink" traceLevel="Verbose" />
      <hosts>
        <host name="[[newCacheNamespace]].cache.windows.net" cachePort="22233" />
      </hosts>
      <securityProperties mode="Message">
        <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="[[secret]]">
        </messageSecurity>
      </securityProperties>
    </dataCacheClient>
    <dataCacheClient name="SslEndpoint">
      <tracing sinkType="DiagnosticSink" traceLevel="Verbose" />
      <hosts>
        <host name="[[newCacheNamespace]].cache.windows.net" cachePort="22243" />
      </hosts>
      <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="true">
        <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="[[secret]]">
        </messageSecurity>
      </securityProperties>
    </dataCacheClient>
  </dataCacheClients>
```

Here is my session state provider config:

```xml
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" useBlobMode="true" dataCacheClientName="default" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Below is the error that I get:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The remote name could not be resolved: '[[oldCacheNamespace]]-cache.accesscontrol.windows.net' 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: '[[oldCacheNamespace]]-cache.accesscontrol.windows.net'

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: '[[oldCacheNamespace]]-cache.accesscontrol.windows.net']
   System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(Uri address, String method, NameValueCollection data) +1243
   System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(String address, String method, NameValueCollection data) +179
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AcsHelpers.GetToken(String serviceNamespace, String acsHostName, String issuerName, String issuerKey, String appliesTo) +523

[DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0030>:SubStatus<ES0001>:ACS request for token failed. One of the reasons could be an invalid authorization token.]
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AcsHelpers.GetToken(String serviceNamespace, String acsHostName, String issuerName, String issuerKey, String appliesTo) +1875
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ClientAcsSecurity.get_Token() +242
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.CacheResolverChannel..ctor(CacheResolverCommunicatorType communicatorType, IDuplexSessionChannel innerChannel, DataCacheSecurity dataCacheSecurity) +559

[CommunicationException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0030>:SubStatus<ES0001>:ACS request for token failed. One of the reasons could be an invalid authorization token.]
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.CacheResolverChannel..ctor(CacheResolverCommunicatorType communicatorType, IDuplexSessionChannel innerChannel, DataCacheSecurity dataCacheSecurity) +833
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.CacheResolverChannelFactory`1.System.ServiceModel.Channels.IChannelFactory<TChannel>.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress to) +274
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.EndPointIdentityChannelFactory`1.System.ServiceModel.Channels.IChannelFactory<TChannel>.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress to) +186
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.WcfClientChannel.CreateChannel(EndpointID endpoint) +557
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ChannelContainer.CreateChannel() +153

[DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0006>:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions. Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size sent from the client.)]
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ResponseBody respBody) +693
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCacheProperties(RequestBody request, SimpleSendReceiveModule sendRcvModule) +1194
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName) +701
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheFactoryWrapper.CreateDataCacheFromFactory(DataCacheFactory factory, String cacheName) +63
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.CacheHelpers.RunCacheCreationHooks(CacheConnectingEventArgs fetchingEventArgs, IDataCacheFactory dataCacheFactory, Object sender, EventHandler`1 fetchingHandler, EventHandler`1 fetchedHandler) +356
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.CreateInternalProvider(IHttpRuntime httpRuntime, SessionInitializationData initData, IDataCacheFactory dataCacheFactory, EventHandler`1 cacheFetching, EventHandler`1 cacheFetched) +447
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.GetInternalProvider() +315
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.CreateNewStoreData(HttpContext context, Int32 timeout) +59
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.InitStateStoreItem(Boolean addToContext) +182
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState() +374
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +2007
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +477
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +312
```

Comment: It sounds like your published role configuration has not been updated. How many role instances are you running? Do you have RDP enabled? Are these web roles or websites?

Comment: This is just when I run locally, I haven't gotten to the point where I am deploying to Azure.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't changing the right configuration. Try removing the web.config and see what happens. You need to verify where your application is physically located within IIS.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but someone might run into this problem in the future.

The fix is:

1. Remove the < hosts> element.
2. Instead, add this element:

   < autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="[[newCacheNamespace].cache.windows.net" />

That's it